# How to plot seaborn's catplot to gridspec

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I have made a 2x2 gridspec and trying to plot the catplot in the second row like so:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5), constrained_layout=True)
gs = GridSpec(nrows=2, ncols=2, figure=fig)

# Chart 1
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0]) 

ax1=sns.countplot(x='product', data = df)    #Countplot 
plt.title('Product sales', fontweight='bold', fontsize = 8)
plt.ylabel('Count', fontsize = 7)
plt.xlabel('Product', fontsize = 7)

# Chart 2
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1]) 
ax2= sns.countplot(x='maritalstatus', data = df)    #Countplot 
plt.title('Marital status of customers', fontweight='bold', fontsize = 8)
plt.ylabel('', fontsize = 7)
plt.xlabel('Marital status', fontsize = 7)

# chart 3
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,:]) 
ax3 = sns.catplot(x = 'product', hue = "gender", col = "maritalstatus", data = df, kind = 'count')

plt.show()
```

But the second row is not plotted by the catplot, but appears below the blank graph.

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `catplot` is a figure-level interface, not an axes-level interface, so you cannot plot it in this way. This is a common problem with other figure-level interfaces such as `displot`, and the workaround I have found is to use the underlying components individually (for `displot` specifically it was `kdeplot` and histogram, for `catplot` you will have to peek into the source code).

You can tell which interfaces are figure or axes level by observing whether they accept the ax argument in their call. In your case you can explore [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) to see which plots are supported and also [the source code](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/categorical.py) for implementation details.